# is it necessary to do server side validation after client side validation with asp.net web site?

Tags: asp.net, client-side, server-side

i am developing an asp.net site and i made validation for the web form using javascript and validation controls.

my question is: is it necessary before inserting data into the database to validate them in server side too or it's not??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, also validating on the server is good practice.

This is because any user can take your HTML page and modify it anyway they choose, removing any and all restrictions and limitations. Double checking on the server prevents such abuse.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, it is**.

Client-side validation can be trivially bypassed by disabling Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Better Use .net Validation .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx

Comment: i used the validation controls like regular expression and required validator but with custom validator for example i am using javascript and Ajax to validate ,so i think i have to re-validate  fields with custom validator only in server side?

Comment: if you use .net validator its automaticly work at server side if client script is disabled, so  i dont thik so its required to write on server side too..

Comment: but i didn't write server side function for them so it will be automatic?

Comment: its not requied but explore more about this  EnableClientScript="false"... you will get idea. by default its true.

Comment: i have another problem i depend in my code in client side because i have controls that be visible only in the client side depends on user input so i will lose all of them when i postback the form for server validation